# How can I get this car out of my Sim's inventory?

Tags: the-sims-3

I made my sim marry a rich sim, who moved in. In his inventory he has one of the most expensive cars. I want to sell it, obviously, since I am ecofriendly and also want to buy all the things, but when I click and drag it into one of the garage slots nothing happens. I'm not able to drag the car at all. The sim had another car in his inventory that this worked on, so I'm not sure why it's not working now.

Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: I wish a car that I could keep in my pocket while I wasn't driving it.

Comment: I don't know how to help you fix the parking spot problem, but if you just want to sell the car, can't you drag it to the inventory selling slot on the left of your inventory?

Comment: No, because clicking and dragging does nothing.

Comment: Can a Sim with the Vehicle Enthusiast trait get so enamoured of a car that he or she refuses to part with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go on a whim here and propose this hypothesis: is it possible that the car was a perk of one of your Sim's old job? A few career paths come with free car perks, the obvious being the patrol car for law enforcement and the firetruck for firefighters. I think the investigators eventually get a car too.

I had this happen to me last night on a Sim who was level 10 firefighter. Quit his job and the firetruck in his inventory got stuck, couldn't drag it at all. I'm having a mind blank on what happened next (this is what happens when I play late at night), but one of the following two things allowed me to drag it again. He used the truck to go somewhere and parked it on his own in its garage spot, after which I could drag it around; or joining the firefighting profession again, at a lower level, made it unlock.

So perhaps you can try both those things. Forcing him to use the car and park it, or see in his career history if any of his old jobs could have given him a work car.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a certain vehicle your "preferred vehicle", it will stay there in your inventory.

Comment: Only if it starts there. If they have a parking space on their lot, they will leave the car there (if possible) each time.